# Problem while configuring wildFly-18 Server on Eclipse

Tags: java, server, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-18

I'm new in the company and they were helping me while I setup the enviroment, I got this error when I started WildFly server (they gave me their wildfly 18):

`

```
09:47:20,106 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
09:47:20,124 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) IJ020018: Enabling <validate-on-match> for java:/goljagen
09:47:20,124 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) IJ020018: Enabling <validate-on-match> for java:/goljagra
09:47:20,129 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/agepos]
09:47:20,129 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/goljagen]
09:47:20,130 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/goljagra]
09:47:22,425 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
09:47:22,439 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Program Files\wildfly-18.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
09:47:22,458 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "archiconEar.ear" (runtime-name: "archiconEar.ear")
09:47:22,760 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
09:47:23,436 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.3.0.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.3) 
09:47:25,221 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."archiconEar.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."archiconEar.ear".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "archiconEar.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0166: Sub deployment archiconWeb.war in jboss-deployment-structure.xml was not found. Available sub deployments: archiconWeb
    at org.jboss.as.server@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.subDeploymentNotFound(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.server@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.deploy(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:221)
    at org.jboss.as.server@10.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    ... 8 more

09:47:25,728 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "archiconEar.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"archiconEar.ear\".STRUCTURE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"archiconEar.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0166: Sub deployment archiconWeb.war in jboss-deployment-structure.xml was not found. Available sub deployments: archiconWeb"}}
09:47:25,747 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "archiconEar.ear" (runtime-name : "archiconEar.ear")
09:47:25,748 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."archiconEar.ear".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "archiconEar.ear"

09:47:25,820 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
09:47:25,823 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
09:47:25,824 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
09:47:25,824 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 18.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.0.Final) started (with errors) in 18868ms - Started 597 of 859 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 408 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

`

We whatched in the jboss-deployment-structur and we have this:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
 <sub-deployment name="archiconWeb.war">
  <dependencies>
   <!-- <module name="org.apache.poi" /> -->
   <module name="org.apache.commons.codec" />
  </dependencies>
 </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

`

this is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <parent>
    <groupId>it.sisal</groupId>
    <artifactId>archicon</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.39-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  
  <artifactId>archiconEar</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  
  
   <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.ear.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpContextName>archicon</wtpContextName>
                    <!-- Tell Maven we are using Java EE 7 -->
                    <version>7</version>
                    <!-- Use Java EE ear libraries as needed. Java EE ear libraries 
                        are in easy way to package any libraries needed in the ear, and automatically 
                        have any modules (EJB-JARs and WARs) use them -->
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@</outputFileNameMapping>
                    <contextRoot>/archicon</contextRoot>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
           </plugins>            
    </build>


   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.sisal</groupId>
        <artifactId>archiconWeb</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.39-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Everyone else got the same file, Do you have any Idea which file should I check and how I can solve this problem.

Thanks to all!!!!

They told me to do:
mvn build, on eclipse do:

- mvn update;
- Project -> clean;
- Project -> build All;
- On the right click on the server I selected: clean than Publish.

[image: directory]

Comment: Is the war file inside the ear ? Check in C:\Program Files\wildfly-18.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments

Comment: hi @ehsavoie in this direcotry I have: C:\Program Files\wildfly-18.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments\archiconEar.ear where inside I have two folfer:
archiconWeb and META-INF, I can't find any .war

Comment: So that's your issue, you should have a archiconWeb.war instead of the folder. Not sure where your configuration is 'wrong'.